# how to use this aggregate function in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

how to calculate aggregate function using mysql database.The following query returns invalid use of group functions.

```
select avg(max(qty)) from tb_name.
```

Comment: Your question in the current form is ambiguous. Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: max will return only one result and you want to take average of max qty, how is it possible

Comment: Use only one function ..either AVG or MAX.... SELECT AVG(qty) FROM tb_name

Comment: ok sir whether is it possible to calculate max(avg(qt))@AzizShaikh @Viswanath polki@Revanayya hiremath

Comment: no it wont, you must try any other way of storing sum of max qty(ies) and number of categories in which you are finding max qty and then divide them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have any groups in your statement and if you just read it like this you should understand why it is not yielding a sensible result:

You say `Give me the average of the maximum value for qty from tb_name`, but since you are not grouping by anything there is only one maximum value.

If you need both values in one query, you can do so, but you need to have a grouping on your query for example like this:

```
select avg(qty), max(qty) from tb_name group by SomethingOtherThanQty
```

From your comments I guess you are indeed looking for a maximum of all averages over some group, for that a query with subquery could look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(AVERAGE) FROM
    (SELECT
            AVG(qty) AS AVERAGE
        FROM tb_name
        GROUP BY YourGroupingCriteria) AS SubQuery
```

Comment: sir is it possible to calculate like this max(avg(qty)) it shows invalid use of group

Comment: @subramani I added one example of how I can imagine a reasonable query to do so, but since I do not know your desired result or your underlying table structure I can only guess ;)

Comment: no sir i need to calculate in single column itself for example i need to calculate (max for the avg) function like this max(avg(qty)) whether is it possible. if it is not so pls tell me reason@ DrCopyPaste

Comment: @subramani you need to add more requirements as to what you need exactly, the `maximum of the average` is equal to the `average` if you only have one group, I imagine you can do a subquery in that you fetch average values of some `GROUP` and run a query on that that returns the maximum average of that subquery, but again what group are we talking about?

Comment: maximum of average in not equal to average sir if it have different id .for example id col contains 1 2 2 3 and qty col contains 10 20 30 40 . now i need to calculate max(avg(qty)) group by id. which may  calculate avg and then max for each id ... sir but this query is not working..@DrCopyPaste

Comment: @subramani take a look at this fiddle, does either of the queries come close to what you want? if not I am still not understanding what you want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c60/4

Comment: thank you so much sir http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c60/11 i got the solution.......@DrCopyPaste

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT AVG(qty) FROM tb_name
```

This will give you the average value of quantity

OR

```
SELECT MAX(qty) FROM tb_name
```

This will give you the maximum value of quanity

Using both AVG and MAX on the same table is both logically and syntax-wise incorrect.

Comment: i need to calculate both in single query like max(avg(qty)) but it shows invalid

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT AVG(SELECT MAX(qty) FROM tb_name) FROM tb_name
```